# how to add condition to spinner on android

Tags: java, android, conditional-statements, android-spinner

i have a spinner in android, i want to check if value in spinner return "LAIN-LAIN" on index 6 it willl visible my edittext, but when i run it, it return to error, this is my code :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinner_bukti = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Pemegang_polis.this, R.layout.spinner_style,identitas);
    spinner_bukti.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown);
    bukti_identitas_pp.setAdapter(spinner_bukti);  

    bukti_identitas_pp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            String Text = bukti_identitas_pp.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (Text=="LAIN-LAIN"){
                edit_bukti_lain_pp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                teks_bukti_lain_pp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                edit_bukti_lain_pp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                teks_bukti_lain_pp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }

    });
```

this is my logcat :

```
11-08 15:04:13.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 15:04:13.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-08 15:04:13.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2845):     at id.co.ajsmsig.formspaj.Pemegang_polis$2.onItemSelected(Pemegang_polis.java:170)
11-08 15:04:13.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2845):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)
11-08 15:04:13.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2845):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
11-08 15:04:13.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2845):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860)
11-08 15:04:13.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2845):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-08 15:04:13.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2845):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-08 15:04:13.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2845):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-08 15:04:13.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2845):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
11-08 15:04:13.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2845):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 15:04:13.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2845):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-08 15:04:13.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2845):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
11-08 15:04:13.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2845):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
11-08 15:04:13.329: E/AndroidRuntime(2845):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i don't know where is my fault.. i hope someone can help me to solve my problem.

Comment: `Text=="LAIN-LAIN"`. Not good. Search for how to compare Strings in Java.

Comment: use `.equals()` method istead of " == "

Comment: What doesn't work? And the exception occurs on line 170, which line is that in your posted example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use:

```
String text = bukti_identitas_pp.getSelectedItem().toString();
if (text.equals("LAIN-LAIN")){
    ...
}
```

The NullPointerException seems to arise because the `edit_bukti_lain_pp` or the `teks_bukti_lain_pp` is not initialized correctly. (At least that would be my first guess...)

Comment: it doesn't work, i have intialized edit_bukti_lain_pp and teks_bukti_lain_pp

Comment: Ok. The stacktrace says that in the onItemSelected method on line 170 there is a NullPointerException. I don't know which of the lines your line 170 is. Try to set a Breakpoint there, debug the app and see what happens.